# How to convert/shred this XML data so that I can load it in SQL Server tables?

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis

We receive multiple xml files like this and I need to load them in SQL Server tables. I tried using SSIS (Data flow - XML source) but it immediately game me columnname error. So now I am trying to shred this file so far haven't had any luck. I am new to XML so any kind of help or suggestions is much appreciated.
 Thanks in advance.

Here is my sample XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ABCDataSet xmlns="http://www.w3.org"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.w3.org http://www.w3.org/media/file_v3/release-3.4/XSDs/ABCDataSet_v3.xsd"><!-- This 3 file was generated from aan application le via an XML Stylesheet Language Transformation (XSLT). -->
   <Header>
      <DemographicGroup>
         <Location.01>474</Location.01>
         <Location.02>474</Location.02>
         <Location.04>08</Location.04>
      </DemographicGroup>
      <ConfigDetails>
         <ConfigDetails.CustomGroup CustomElementID="5303300">
            <ConfigDetails.01>XYZCSS_OnsetDateTime</ConfigDetails.01>
            <ConfigDetails.02>The onset time.</ConfigDetails.02>
            <ConfigDetails.03>9902003</ConfigDetails.03>
            <ConfigDetails.04>9923001</ConfigDetails.04>
            <ConfigDetails.05>9903007</ConfigDetails.05>
         </ConfigDetails.CustomGroup>
         <ConfigDetails.CustomGroup CustomElementID="5303301">
            <ConfigDetails.01>XYZCSS_FD</ConfigDetails.01>
            <ConfigDetails.02>CSS FD value</ConfigDetails.02>
            <ConfigDetails.03>9902009</ConfigDetails.03>
            <ConfigDetails.04>9923001</ConfigDetails.04>
            <ConfigDetails.05>9903007</ConfigDetails.05>
            <ConfigDetails.06>Normal</ConfigDetails.06>
            <ConfigDetails.06>Abnormal</ConfigDetails.06>
         </ConfigDetails.CustomGroup>        
      </ConfigDetails>
      <CustomerCare>
         <Cust_Entry>
            <Cust_Entry.01>9b09f0bd84b24f858073abb30099s55</Cust_Entry.01>
            <Cust_Entry.SoftwareApplicationGroup>
               <Cust_Entry.02>XYZ Solutions</Cust_Entry.02>
               <Cust_Entry.03>XYZ App</Cust_Entry.03>
               <Cust_Entry.04>5.0</Cust_Entry.04>
            </Cust_Entry.SoftwareApplicationGroup>
         </Cust_Entry>
         <Cust_Response>
            <Cust_Response.AgencyGroup>
               <Cust_Response.01>474</Cust_Response.01>
               <Cust_Response.02>ABC Corp</Cust_Response.02>
            </Cust_Response.AgencyGroup>
            <Cust_Response.03>20-044818</Cust_Response.03>
            <Cust_Response.04>20-044818</Cust_Response.04>
            <Cust_Response.ServiceGroup>
               <Cust_Response.05>2205001</Cust_Response.05>
            </Cust_Response.ServiceGroup>
            <Cust_Response.07>2207007</Cust_Response.07>
            <Cust_Response.08>2208013</Cust_Response.08>
            <Cust_Response.09>2209011</Cust_Response.09>
            <Cust_Response.10 xsi:nil="true" NV="7701003"/>
            <Cust_Response.11 xsi:nil="true" NV="7701003"/>
            <Cust_Response.12 xsi:nil="true" NV="7701003"/>
            <Cust_Response.13>T19</Cust_Response.13>
            <Cust_Response.14>T19</Cust_Response.14>
            <Cust_Response.15>2215003</Cust_Response.15>
            <Cust_Response.23>2223001</Cust_Response.23>
            <Cust_Response.24>2224015</Cust_Response.24>
         </Cust_Response>
       </CustomerCare>
   </Header>
</ABCDataSet>
```

Comment: Use xml task in SSIS to import data into a table you could create xml schema definition in case. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/control-flow/xml-task?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: (1) Your XML element names quite unusual. Did you manually change them to obfuscate real XML? (2) What is your desired output from the SSIS XML Source Adaptor? (3) You can use SSIS XML Task XSLT transformation to simplify the XML, so the XML Source Adaptor will be able to  ingest the XML.

Comment: Yes. I only changed some texts on column names but the structure is the same.  Since these are new files sent from a vendor for the first time,we are still not sure of what the table structure would look like. Infact,  I was hoping to see some columns and data in a more readable format from this xml. But haven't been able to figure that out so far.

Comment: That looks mighty unpleasant to deal with in SSIS. I suspect you're going to end up with a lot of .NET parsing this as this is likely more complex than the native tooling is going to support. In a case like this, I'd reach out to the vendor and ask about what the data looks like on their end. Otherwise, you're stuck pondering what it means when a customer response is in an agency group versus a service group. Is response 10 always going to be a true/false value or is that dependent upon response 05 being in a group?

Comment: Please specify the expected output fitting to the given sample.

Comment: Thanks everyone for your comments. We ended up getting data in csv format instead of this xml format.

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following to convert **ANY XML** file to a SQL Table. You can still used ssis to read and convert one by one calling this table function.

USE:

```
select *  from Utility.FlattenXml('your xml’)
```

PROCEDURE:

```
USE [YOUR_DB]
GO
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE FUNCTION [Utility].[FlattenXml](@xmlDoc XML)  
RETURNS TABLE 
AS RETURN 
WITH CTE AS ( 

    SELECT 
            1 AS lvl,  
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
            CAST(NULL AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
            CAST(1 AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
            CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS FullPath,  
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')  
            + N'[' 
            + CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)  
            + N']' AS XPath,  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Tree,  
            x.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Value,  
            x.query('.') AS this,         
            x.query('*') AS t,  
            CAST(CAST(1 AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX)) AS Sort,  
            CAST(1 AS INT) AS ID  
    FROM @xmlDoc.nodes('/*') a(x)  
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
            p.lvl + 1 AS lvl,  
            c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS Name,  
            CAST(p.Name AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS ParentName, 
            CAST(p.Position AS INT) AS ParentPosition, 
            CAST(N'Element' AS NVARCHAR(20)) AS NodeType,  
            CAST(p.FullPath + N'/' + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS FullPath,  
            CAST(p.XPath + N'/'+ c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')+ N'['+ CAST(ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
            ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS NVARCHAR)+ N']' AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS XPath,  
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)')
            ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS Position, 
            CAST( SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE(N'-', 1) + c.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX)) AS Tree,  
            CAST( c.value('text()[1]','NVARCHAR(MAX)') AS NVARCHAR(MAX) ) AS Value, c.query('.') AS this,  
            c.query('*') AS t,  
            CAST(p.Sort + CAST( (lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS VARBINARY(4)) AS VARBINARY(MAX) ) AS Sort,  
            CAST((lvl + 1) * 1024 + (ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) * 2) AS INT)
            
    FROM CTE p  
    CROSS APPLY p.t.nodes('*') b(c)), cte2 AS (  
                                                SELECT 
                                                lvl AS Depth,  
                                                Name AS NodeName,  
                                                ParentName, 
                                                ParentPosition, 
                                                NodeType,  
                                                FullPath,  
                                                XPath,  
                                                Position, 
                                                Tree AS TreeView,  
                                                Value,  
                                                this AS XMLData,  
                                                Sort, 
                                                ID
                                                FROM cte  
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
            p.lvl,  
            x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            p.Name, 
            p.Position, 
            CAST(N'Attribute' AS NVARCHAR(20)),  
            p.FullPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            p.XPath + N'/@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            1, 
            SPACE(2 * p.lvl - 1) + N'|' + REPLICATE('-', 1)  
            + N'@' + x.value('local-name(.)','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            x.value('.','NVARCHAR(MAX)'),  
            NULL,  
            p.Sort,  
            p.ID + 1  
    FROM CTE p  
    CROSS APPLY this.nodes('/*/@*') a(x)  
    )  

    SELECT into [your table]
            ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Sort, ID) AS ID,  
            ParentName, ParentPosition,Depth, NodeName, Position,   
            NodeType, FullPath, XPath, TreeView, Value, XMLData 
    FROM CTE2
```